# How can a name exist before anything was Created

Tags: midrash, theology, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, practical-kabbalah

BH

I heard “before the world was created it was the Holy one blessed be He and His Great Name alone”

> עד שלא נברא העולם, היה הקדוש ברוך הוא ושמו הגדול בלבד

[Source](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.3.2?lang=bi&with=all)

How can a name exist before everything was created as wouldn’t a name and Hashem existing together signify multiplicity?

Comment: shmo might not mean "name" in the discrete sense, but "identity" or "rank" which exists as a description of Hashem who, alone, existed.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.5.5?lang=bi&with=all

Comment: @שלום What are you highlighting?

Comment: @RabbiKaii, from שמו ודעתו אחד…

Answer (score 2):

I heard this *mashal* in a shiur recently, which is based on a *sicha* or *maamar* in Chabad Chassidus, that helped me get a small handle on this very lofty idea.

Firstly, the question of "what is His Name before creation" is a very subtle topic that is dealt with, for example, in [this Torah Ohr](https://www.sefaria.org/Torah%20Ohr,%20Vayakhel%201:13). Whatever this Kabbalistic point is, we can still discuss the answer to your question by approaching it as "before Adam and Chava were created".

> When you look at a beautiful piece of art, the first thing you "think
> about" is *the art*. It is beautiful, and it captures your attention
> for hours as you look at and enjoy every last detail. Eventually, *at
> some point*, you'll think "I wonder who did this!"
>
> This is not so when you look at a trash heap. The very first thing you
> think about when you see a trash heap is "who did this?!".

When the world was formless and void, Hashem was revealed. His Name was fully revealed. If, *hypothetically*, someone was there to have a look, they would immediately think only of Him, because the world itself is nothingness. All the more so before there was even a formless void.

On the other hand, certainly once there was Adam and Chava, then we don't think about Hashem immediately. There's action, there's a snake, an apple, he blamed her, etc. Eventually we ask, who did and what is their name? I.e. what was their goal? [Names and purpose are linked in Torah thought](https://aish.com/judaism-the-power-of-names/).

This is part of the deeper idea of Hashem creating the world out of nothing. Not just no raw materials, but also the world *itself* offers no compelling reason for it's need to be created. That need comes only from Hashem, and is indeed the purpose of creation.